# How can I add soft hyphenation to all words in a file based on locale?

Tags: c++, layout, text, tex, hyphenation

I would like to add hyphenation in a C++ program.  I have files of words for each locale.

Is it possible to run each file through a program that adds all possible soft hyphenation, maybe via TeX style hyphenation or via some OSX magic?

Or is there a good reliable C library to check soft hyphenation at runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are no shortcuts: you need a set of dictionaries for each locale, as discussed in [What are the rules for splitting words at the end of a line?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line).  For English, there are some free dictionaries, e.g., this [Free English language hyphenation dictionary](http://hindson.com.au/info/free/free-english-language-hyphenation-dictionary/)

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  How would I find dictionaries for other locales?

Comment: As I said - no shortcuts (web searches in the given languages seems the only way, unless you happen to find someone who has made a study of the topic).